# Layout term for bar or rectangle of solid color

Tags: page-layout, terminology

I'm trying to find the term for a rectangle or figure made of rectangles of solid color, as found sometimes near the title on the front page of publications and websites. I have looked at various glossaries of page layout terminology and so far have not found the term for this.

Example 1: the black rectangle above the title (“The Word”) in the following image.

[image: a sample page layout]

Example 2: the neon cherry L-shaped thing around the title.

[image: the front page of a publication from 2002]

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific general term for these.

InDesign has a formatting feature for this called [Paragraph Rules](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-paragraphs.html#add_rules_lines_above_or_below_paragraphs), which can sit over, direcly under or below the headline and can have any weight from a thin line to a solid bar.

The L shape could be called a *frame*.

Comment: Well, I think “rules” and “frames” *are* appropriate terms

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a name for each of these elements, in Spanish at least it exists, in the image below I put the names in Spanish and the literal translation.

All these elements are included in what is called "grafismo" (graphism, graphics) within the page.

[image: page graphics]

- *Zócalos*: solid color graphics touching the page sides bleeding, specially top and bottom rectangular shapes. Google Translate gives many options for *zócalo*, I don't know the right one for this case: plinth, baseboard, skirting board, socle, skirting, wainscot. Depending the touching with the bleeding side, it can be upper, lower, left or right. If the contact is in two
  sides: bottom-left corner socket.
- *Pastillas* (pads): solid color graphics, especially the rectangular ones, that DON'T touch the page bleed.
- *Cenefas* (valances): sockets and pads with decoration instead of flat
  filling.
- *Pastillas de texto* (text pads): pad containing text.
- *Frames* or *text frames*: the elements that surround a text without filling. If it's incomplete *container* or *container frame*.
- *Filetes* (fillets): linear graphics.

---

Anyway, when there are doubts about the name of an element in composition and editorial design, imagine the description of the page by phone:

> The Computing magazine cover has under the name an incomplete bottom-left red container frame